# Lasagna plots in R

Tags: r, graph

I have been reading about [Lasagna plots](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/bit/compintro/bruce/lasagna_newplots.pdf) in `R`. In the appendix to the paper in the link, the authors have a lot of code to implement these plots. But it's a pdf and I can't copy into RStudio (at least, I haven't figured out how). Has anyone made these into a package or does anyone have the code in a more usable format?

Comment: These look tasty, +1 ...from browsing fig. 1, I guess that some targeted use of `heatmap()` might get you somewhere in the direction...

Comment: From the article: "Lasagna plots: A saucy alternative to spaghetti plots" :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try contacting the paper's authors?

Comment: Heatmap is indeed used. Perhaps I wasn't clear... the code is in the supplement ... hundreds and hundreds of lines of it. I just want to be able to run in without having to retype it all.

Comment: @Joran I did that, I haven't heard back. I figured maybe someone else had done this, so I thought I'd ask here, as well. (Plus, I spread the word about a cool plot).

Comment: Depends on the type of pdf:  If you select the text tool (in Adobe Reader or your choice of PDF viewer), you're not able to Copy and Paste?  An alternative is to run a PDF document through Calibre.  But: I see no code at all in your linked document.  Where is the code itself?

Comment: Damn, the syntax in the supplement seems indeed unwieldy: Swihart et al apparently also defined plotting functions with more than 30 (!) parameters without setting any default values; for practical reasons it might even be more efficient if someone actually read the description in the paper and defined his/her own implementation (and maybe be kind enough to post it below)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lasagna plots appear to be exactly heat maps, although the name is cute. Heat maps are plotted very well in other packages. Consider the first example plot in the code pointed out by Carl Witthoft. You can reproduce it in `ggplot` like this:

```
## Create the data
palette <- brewer.pal(4, "PuOr")[-2]
## the matrix containing data for Figure 02a
H.mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=4, ncol=6)
H.mat[1, 1:6] = 100*c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
H.mat[2, 1:6] = 100*c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1)
H.mat[3, 1:6] = 100*c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3)
H.mat[4, 1:6] = 100*c(3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
rownames(H.mat)<-c('P1','T1','P2','T2')
colnames(H.mat)<-seq(ncol(H.mat))
names(dimnames(H.mat))<-c('Subject','Time')
H.df<-melt(H.mat)
```

Depending on what you want you can get different types of colouring.

```
# For continuous values.
ggplot(H.df,aes(x=Time,y=Subject,fill=value)) + geom_tile(colour='black')
```

[image]

```
# If you consider the value to be categorical.
ggplot(H.df,aes(x=Time,y=Subject,fill=factor(value))) + 
  geom_tile(colour='black')
```

[image]

```
# If you want those exact colours the author used:
col<-palette[match(ordered(H.df$value),levels(ordered(H.df$value)))]
ggplot(H.df,aes(x=Time,y=Subject,fill=col)) + 
  geom_tile(colour='black') + scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to properly use the exact colours the author did, so I used a cheesy hack. If someone can tell me how to properly feed custom colours to `ggplot` in a more natural way, let me know and I'll change the answer.

Comment: I think you've got it!

Answer (score 4):

To answer the actual question:  the code is in a pdf document here:  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2937254/bin/NIHMS225391-supplement-1.pdf

And I easily selected the code in Adobe Reader and copy/pasted it into a text document.

Comment: Dang. That worked this time. Thanks.  Anyway, now the reference to Lasagna plots is here. However, given the comment by @TexB, I am not sure if I should mark this as answered, as there might be better code.

Answer (score 1):

After many years, a github repo has been started based on nograpes answer.

https://github.com/swihart/lasagnar